# multilingual site with views

Tags: views, i18n-l10n

I'm trying to set an english/spanish website and I've already set in my post types which are the types I want to be translatable. I also translated the posts but I'm not really sure how to set the views to display the content based on the language... I want the spanish posts to show up in domain.com/es/whatever/route ... and the english posts to show up in domain.com/whatever/route ... right now, both paths show the same content (the posts in English and the posts in Spanish)...

I'm guessing I need to somehow set contextual filters and relationships but I'm not so sure about how. Could I get a hand with that?

Answer (score 1):

for Views module add filter: Node translation: Language ->  Current user's language.